# Content database to SharePoint 2010 Foundation

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am having `wss_content` database of SharePoint 2010 Foundation. So I want use that database in new SharePoint 2010 Foundation server which I want to install on Windows 2008 Server R2 (HyperV).

So should I do it...?

Answer (score 1):

What i understand is, You want to use the SharePoint Foundation 2010 database to new SharePoint Server 2010 farm. Yes you can use it.

- build a new SharePoint 2010 farm and create & configure the web app, service applications.
- backup the WSS_ContentDB from SPF 2010 SQL server( SQL backup)
- Restore the Database on SP server 2010 SQL server
- Now attach the Database to the desired web app.

Answer (score 0):

Backup and restore the DB into your new Server. Then while creating an application attach your old db here there.

Please refer to this [article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748604.aspx) for more details, although this is for SP 2013 but steps remains almost the same.